# c# winform RichTextBox : unable to get exact height

Tags: .net, height, richtextbox

In our application, we have used Datagrid with Richtextbox.

It works fine, except that height of richtextbox is set depending on the cell height.

We want to calculate the exact richtextbox height, by setting its width and its content.

Is this possible ?

Comment: cant you set the height to auto or stretch

Comment: Based on the richtextbox height , the data-grid row height will be set for that row. Does setting height to auto/stretch will get the richtextbox's actual height when content is set ?

Comment: you can read about the help property here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.height.aspx